# Remove comma from while statement

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

Im looking for a way to output my wordpress custom fields in this format:

```
  "genre": [
        "genre 1",
         "genre 2",
         "genre 3"
  ]
```

using this code:

```html
"genre": [
  <?php if( have_rows('genres') ):
      while ( have_rows('genres') ) : the_row();
          $genre = get_sub_field('genre');
          ?>
          "<?= $genre; ?>",
    <?php
      endwhile;

  endif; ?>
  ]
```

But the result (logically) has a comma at the last genre, which creates errors.

```html
"genre": [
        "genre 1",
         "genre 2",
         "genre 3",
  ]
```

How can i fix this?:

Comment: Just do `json_encode($genres)`;

Comment: It returns: {"genre":["genre1","genre2","genre3"]} we have a sollution if we can manage to strip the { } from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Wordpress (and never will) but that's JSON, why not:

```
while ( have_rows('genres') ) : the_row();
    $genres[] = get_sub_field('genre');
endwhile;

echo json_encode(['genre' => $genres]);
```

Comment: Allright this is getting really close. it returns:
{"genre":["genre1","genre2","genre3"]} we have a sollution if we can manage to strip the { } from it

Comment: that's not valid json but `echo trim(json_encode(['genre' => $genres]), '{}');`.

Comment: i know, but its part of more code which is now approved by the google structured data test tool